# Unable to drag and drop element from 1 div to another div element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have been trying to drag an element from one div (below)

```
<article class="media-gallery-item mg-html5">
    <div class="mg-thumbnail" draggable="true" data-popcorn-plugin-type="sequencer" data-butter-draggable-type="plugin" data-butter-popcorn-options="{"source":"some_url","thumbnail":"some_url","start":0,"end":10,"from":0,"title":"bdgxkvtbs1.mp4","duration":2.83,"hidden":false,"asset_id":"1457","asset_width":"1280","asset_height":"720","asset_name":"video1.MOV","soundeffects":0}" >
        <img src="some_url">
```

into another div

```
<div class="butter-track" data-butter-track-id="1"></div>
```

for dropping onto the element we need can also use pixel values.

I have tried the below code but it didn't drag the element into the `div`. I could even not see it dragging the element at run time.

```
WebElement src = driver.findElementBy(By.xpath(".//div[@class='mg-thumbnail']"));
WebElement dest = driver.findElementBy(By.xpath(".//div[@class='butter-track']"));
Actions act = new Action();
act.clickAndHold(src).moveByoffset(src, 0,300).release().build().perform();
```

I also tried using:

```
act.clickAndHold(src).dragAndDrop(src, dest).build().perform();
```

But none dropped the element. (i also could not see the dragging of the element at runtime)

**NOTE- the code works for drag and drop as i used earlier but here I'm dragging the element from 1 div to another div so this might be creating the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

@pranky301 : Here is the Slight modification in you code.
Please try this and let me know what happens

```
WebElement src = driver.findElementBy(By.xpath(".//div[@class='mg-thumbnail']"));
WebElement dest = driver.findElementBy(By.xpath(".//div[@class='butter-track']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action drag = builder.clickAndHold(Src).moveToElement(dest).release(dest).build( );
drag.perform( );
```

Comment: This has really worked something.the element has changed the UI where it has dropped the element however the element is not visible at its new location.
can you suggest a way in which it drops using pixel values ?

Comment: Sure , When you say that element has changed its UI, which Element is it a SRC or DEST? Why we need to use pixel values for Drag and Drop as it could be on of the non-reliable way to do?

Comment: i believe we need to use pixel values because i have to drop at particular pixel value at the "DEST". and the UI changes at DEST but element is not seen dropped.

Comment: @pranky301 : Please refer  link https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/tag/drag-and-drop/

Comment: i can drag the element from dest to dest (changing the pixel values) but m facing the issue to drag the element from src to dest. Both are different things.. but thanks for your help. Please suggest if you can also help in dragging from src to dest at certain pixel value on the dest.

Comment: I doubt about the Soruce and Dest are in the same frame. If not then please follow the link below and you will also find some helpful solutions. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4202

Comment: HI Rupesh, i also had the same doubt earlier but then i checked and got that there is no frame in on my page.

m still awaiting the solution!! PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods have previously worked for me when dragging and dropping items from one element to another:

```
WebElement src = driver.findElement(...);
WebElement dest = driver.findElement(...);

new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(src, dest).build().perform();
```

or by coordinates:

```
new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(src, "xOffset", "yOffset").build().perform();
```